# Remote debugging in Eclipse IDE for C/C++

Tags: linux, eclipse, gdb, embedded, gdbserver

I am running my code on the target (embedded pc) using a remote debug application mode in *Eclipse* by specifying the port number and hostname.

I am using *gdbserver* on the target and manual remote debug aplication on the client.

When I debug my code on the target, it moves into debug mode. After that, there is no connect option in the debug mode. Only there is a start, reconnect and so on.

Why there is no connect option in debug mode?

Comment: What does "it moves into debug mode" mean?  What is "it" in this context - the target or the IDE?  Did you mean "Eclipse switches to the Debug perspective" perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean you just want to connect, without loading new code or resetting the CPU?

try unchecking 'Load Image'.

[image]